# Why I am getting command not found in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I am working on a hadoop project on Ubuntu 14.04. Whenever I give the `start-all.sh` or `start-dfs.sh`, it gives me command not found message. What should I do?

Comment: When I was working on hadoop I was typing the command on terminal

Comment: Show us what you did and what you see.

Answer (score 0):

You are not running the command in right environment. 
The start-all.sh(deprecated) or start-dfs.sh command lies in /hadoop/bin directory. You have to find your hadoop home directory and find bin folder in it, then run the command

./start-dfs.sh

Answer (score 0):

Do below inside your **~/.bashrc**

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

then run **source ~/.bashrc** file. Now command should work.

Answer (score 0):

This situation should be that the bin environment variable of Hadoop is not configured properly.

Modify the `vi /etc/profile` file

```
export $HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hadoop  #the  directory  where  your hadoop installed

export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

then

```
source /etc/profile
```